# SharePoint Web Service and load balancer

Tags: web-services, web-config, sharepoint-2013, load-balancing

I have a farm with 2 WFE servers with load balancer. I setup these configurations :

- An alternate access mapping to my web application (http://my-intranet
  to http://web-application:21545)
- A header to iis web application

I have an implemeted web service under _vti_bin/mycustomWebService/ folder

I added the below configuration to my web services web config.

```html
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true">
```

When i'm calling my web services, a message tell me that i need to setup multipleSiteBindingsEnabled to "True". It's already set !!!

I putted this entry to the web application web config for testing, the service call succeed, but CSOM is no more working !

Can you help me please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.
I have to add the sharepoint factory to my svc file. So my svc content is as folow

```html
<%@ ServiceHost Service="Services.MyService" Factory="Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Services.MultipleBaseAddressWebServiceHostFactory, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerRuntime, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"  %>
```